# Beaker 1.5.1 not creating cache file

Tags: python, caching, pylons, beaker

Recently one of our app servers went down, when it was rebooted the Python Beaker module stopped producing cache files.

The error I am getting is:

```
Error - <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: 'ver'
URL: http://127.0.0.1:3002/menuadmin/
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/WebError-0.10.1-py2.6.egg/weberror/errormiddleware.py', line 162 in __call__
  app_iter = self.application(environ, sr_checker)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Beaker-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/beaker/middleware.py', line 73 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Beaker-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/beaker/middleware.py', line 152 in __call__
  return self.wrap_app(environ, session_start_response)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/repoze.who-1.0.18-py2.6.egg/repoze/who/middleware.py', line 107 in __call__
  app_iter = app(environ, wrapper.wrap_start_response)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/inm-1.0.0dev_r2361-py2.6.egg/inm/middleware/middlewarecomponents.py', line 40 in _GroupsMiddleware
  return app(environ, start_response)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/inm-1.0.0dev_r2361-py2.6.egg/inm/middleware/middlewarecomponents.py', line 121 in _AIMSStackedUserMiddleware
  return app(environ, start_response)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pulse-0.1.2-py2.6.egg/pulse/middleware.py', line 183 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Routes-1.12-py2.6.egg/routes/middleware.py', line 131 in __call__
  response = self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pylons-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 125 in __call__
  response = self.dispatch(controller, environ, start_response)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pylons-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 324 in dispatch
  return controller(environ, start_response)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/menuadmin-0.9.7dev_r0-py2.6.egg/menuadmin/lib/base.py', line 18 in __call__
  return WSGIController.__call__(self, environ, start_response)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pylons-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 217 in __call__
  response = self._inspect_call(self.__before__)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pylons-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 107 in _inspect_call
  result = self._perform_call(func, args)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pylons-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 60 in _perform_call
  return func(**args)
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/menuadmin-0.9.7dev_r0-py2.6.egg/menuadmin/controllers/admin.py', line 27 in __before__
  mcm.checkout()
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/menuadmin-0.9.7dev_r0-py2.6.egg/menuadmin/controllers/pagecache.py', line 35 in checkout
  ver = cm.get('ver')
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Beaker-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/beaker/cache.py', line 222 in get
  return self._get_value(key, **kw).get_value()
File '/opt/csw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Beaker-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/beaker/container.py', line 257 in get_value
  raise KeyError(self.key)
KeyError: 'ver'
```

Ive gone right back through the modules and found that the cache directory is:

```
cache_dir = /opt/pyapps/menuadmin/data
```

The code creating the cache (a controller module from the main application called pagecache.py):

```
cm = Cache('page_cache',type='ext:memcached',url=config['beaker.session.url'],data_dir=config['pylons.cache_dir'])
```

But when I visit this directory, there is no cache file there.

Can anyone think of why beaker would suddenly throw this error? Could it be some sort of permissions error maybe?

Comment: maybe new beaker doesnt work with pylons I have another troubles then install pylons with pip and pip get the latest paster.

Comment: Im reluctant to change things like the beaker version, it worked previously but now it seems to have broken for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what actually caused this, some sort of server reset Im guessing, but I managed to hack the program and force it to create a new save file in the beaker directory.